# Filter array objet 2 dimensions by text

Tags: javascript

I need to filter a two dimensional array in JS, I know there is the accumulator could you explain me how to do it please

```
let listItems = [
  {
    category: false,
    items: [
      { value: 1, label: 'Disabled'},
      { value: 2, label: 'Carole Poland'},
      { value: 3, label: 'Wanda Howard'},
    ],
  },
  {
    category: 'Suggestions',
    items: [
      { value: 4, label: 'Robin Counts'},
      { value: 5, label: 'Alex Doe'},
    ],
  },
  {
    category: 'Batiment',
    items: [
      { value: 6, label: 'Vincent Howi'},
      { value: 7, label: 'Alex Zusk'},
    ],
  }
];
```

Wanted result after filter by label 'Alex'

```
let listItems = [
    { category: 'Batiment', items: [{ value: 7, label: 'Alex Zusk'}] },
    { category: 'Suggestions', items: [{ value: 5, label: 'Alex Doe'}] }
];


<input 
  type="text" 
  id="myInput"
  onkeyup="myFunction()" 
  placeholder="Search.." 
/>

function myFunction() {
     input = document.getElementById("myInput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   console.log('Search :', filter);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z03gjdpo/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating a list.
- In every iteration, using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), get items whose label includes the target string. If the latter exist, push a new object to the accumulator with `category` and filtered `items`.

```js
const listItems = [
  {
    category: false,
    items: [ { value: 1, label: 'Disabled'}, { value: 2, label: 'Carole Poland'}, { value: 3, label: 'Wanda Howard'} ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Suggestions',
    items: [ { value: 4, label: 'Robin Counts'}, { value: 5, label: 'Alex Doe'} ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Batiment',
    items: [ { value: 6, label: 'Vincent Howi'}, { value: 7, label: 'Alex Zusk'} ]
  }
];
const target = 'Alex';

const filteredListItems = listItems.reduce((list, { category, items = [] }) => {
  const filteredItems = items.filter(({ label }) => label.includes(target));
  if(filteredItems.length > 0) { list.push({ category, items: filteredItems }); }
  return list;
}, []);

console.log(filteredListItems);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !! I better understand the operation of the accumulator combined with the filter thanks to your example

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using `flatMap` to serve as a combination of `filter` and `map`, like this:

```js
const byLabel = (xs) => (target) => xs .flatMap (
  ({items, ...rest}, _, __, 
  filteredItems = items .filter (({label}) => label .includes (target))
) => filteredItems .length ? [{...rest, items: filteredItems}] : [])

const listItems = [{category: false, items: [{value: 1, label: "Disabled"}, {value: 2, label: "Carole Poland"}, {value: 3, label: "Wanda Howard"}]}, {category: "Suggestions", items: [{value: 4, label: "Robin Counts"}, {value: 5, label: "Alex Doe"}]}, {category: "Batiment", items: [{value: 6, label: "Vincent Howi"}, {value: 7, label: "Alex Zusk"}, {value: 8, label: "Alex Again"}]}]

console .log (byLabel (listItems) ('Alex'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We filter each list of items in the usual manner, and then we include either an empty array, if the filtered result is empty, or an array containing a copy of the original object with the filtered results replacing the original ones.

The `_`, and `__` parameters are just placeholder because `flatMap` passes index and array parameters we want to ignore.

Comment: Thank you for your enriching answer with flatMap which works as well as the accumulator !

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach with reduce! Alternatively you could also do "double filter" (nested filter):

```js
function getItemsByLabel(listItems, label) {
    return listItems.filter((item) => {
        const filtered = item.items.filter((inner) => {
            return inner.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(label.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        });
        if (filtered.length) {
            item.items = filtered;
        };

        return filtered.length;
    })
}

console.log(getItemsByLabel(listItems, 'alex'));
```